# Joi circular dependency error with when condition

Tags: node.js, validation, circular-dependency, joi

I have 3 query parameters **longitude**, **latitude**, and **radius**.

I have 3 possible condition:

- **radius** - empty, **longitude** and **latitude** with some value
- all 3 parameters with value
- all 3 parameters empty

In all other cases send validation error.

e.g.

**longitude**=3.12 - error

**latitude**=2.12, **radius**=3.2 - error

**longitude**=12.12, **latitude**=2.12 - ok

My schema look like this one:

```
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    longitude: Joi.number().optional().error(new Error('LBL_BAD_LONGITUDE'))
      .when('latitude', { is: Joi.exist(), then: Joi.number().required() })
      .when('radius', { is: Joi.exist(), then: Joi.number().required() }),
    latitude: Joi.number().optional().error(new Error('LBL_BAD_LATITUDE'))
      .when('longitude', { is: Joi.exist(), then: Joi.number().required() })
      .when('radius', { is: Joi.exist(), then: Joi.number().required() }),
    radius: Joi.number().optional().error(new Error('LBL_BAD_RADIUS')),
  });
```

As result I get error

```
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: item added into group latitude created a dependencies error
```

Any idea of how to validate these 3 parameters?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not far off.. the trick here is to pick up on your `longitude and latitude with some value` requirement.

```
Joi.object().keys({
    radius: Joi.number(),
    latitude: Joi.number().when('radius', { is: Joi.exist(), then: Joi.required() }),
    longitude: Joi.number().when('radius', { is: Joi.exist(), then: Joi.required() })
}).and('latitude', 'longitude');
```

The [`.and()`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#objectandpeers) modifier creates a peer dependency between `latitude` and `longitude`; if either exists then the other must also exist. However it's also valid to omit both keys as neither are strictly required (helps with `all 3 parameters empty`).

By using `.and()` we only need to add the `.when()` modifications based on whether `radius` exists or not.

Only the following payload formats are valid:

```
{
    latitude: 1.1,
    longitude: 2.2,
    radius: 3
}

{
    latitude: 1.1,
    longitude: 2.2
}

{}
```

Comment: This solution works, but the ValidationErros thrown by `.and()` will always have no `path`. Basically, the errors cannot effectively be traced back to specific properties. This seems to be a limitation of `.and()`. So it would be preferable to do what OP is trying, so that the errors show up on the specific field paths